# Trying to sort out Two Weapon Fighting modifiers

Tags: pathfinder-1e, combat, two-weapon-fighting

Level 12 Fighter.

+12 /   +7 /    +2

Strength 20

+17 Melee Atk mod (BAB +STR)

Offhand weapon is light (Main hand and offhand are the same weapon)

So normally I would be at a +17 / +12 / +7 for my attacks

Feats:

- 2 Weapon Fighting
- Weapon Focus
- Improved 2 Weapon Fighting

I get all this, but I am not sure how to calculate my Main hand and offhand.

It looks like the main hand only ever gets a -2 to hit but the offhand gets a -2 on the first swing and a -5 on the second swing.

Also, I am not sure how many total swings I get in a full attack. It looks like I get 5, instead of the normal three.

Can you all help me sort out how many attacks I get total, and what the modifiers are? I feel silly here, but I don't want to make a mistake at the gaming table.

Comment: Is Weapon Focus on your main-hand weapon, your off-hand weapon, or both?

Comment: Sorry, both weapons are the same. So yes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Main Hand:**

+16/+11/+6

The first attack is **12 + 5** (Strength) **+1** (Weapon Focus) **-2** (Two-Weapon Fighting).  The other attacks are at a -5 and -10, determined by the base attack bonus.

**Off Hand:**

+16/+11

The same penalties and bonuses apply to the first attack, and the second attack is at a -5 penalty as per the Improved Two-Weapon Fighting feat.  The -2 from Two-Weapon Fighting always applies, in addition to that -5.

This does not take into account any bonus from the weapon(s) being magical, or from the [Weapon Training](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/fighter#TOC-Weapon-Training-Ex-) Fighter class ability.  Either of those could affect the attack bonuses if they apply.  Weapon Training could either give an additional +1 or +2 to all attacks with these weapons depending on if you selected the corresponding group at 5th level or 9th level.

Comment: I will most likely stack the weapon training on it.

So I will bump the numbers accordingly. Thank you very much for your time in this.